# Change keymap in Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I've applied the default (IntellJ IDEA) keymap to the Visual Studion and want to change some mapping to my custom, for example Generate Code (Alt+Ins) . How can I to do it or it is impossible .

P.S.Visual Studio 2010, Resharper 6.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard` and find the relevant ReSharper shortcut in the list (I think the one you mentioned is called `ReSharper.ReSharper_Generate`).

Put your cursor in the **Press shortcut keys** box, press then shortcut combination you want to use for it, and then press the **Assign** button. You should now be able to use your new shortcut to access the command you chose.

Answer (score 0):

Menu - ReSharper > Options... > Environment > Visual Studio Integration > Kayboard Shortcuts - you can choose VS

Comment: But, I do not want to choose Visual Studion Shortcuts, I just want to change one key mapping in Default Resharper KeyMap, like in IntellJ IDEA you can create your own keymap, just a copy default and change a few mapping to your custom.